# I'm Facing this problem in Andorid Studio.How to Solve this problem

Tags: flutter, emulation, platform

[image]
when i am running my flutter app on Emulator,i am facing this problem and i don't know how to solve.

Comment: The error is quite obvious: *Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio*

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager  from android studio. and click on this icon [image]

and select android 30
[image]

and apply it and try to re run again.

Comment: android-30 Android SDK Platform 30 is partlialy install but not running